# Child component's local state changes when change happens inside parent component : ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, react-table

I have a situation where I am implementing custom dropdown filter for a table in react. I have set of dropdown values for each column and there is a Apply button.

I have maintained a child component for this which takes in drop down values  and sends the selected one's back to parent.

The filtering happens but when I open this dropdown again the checkbox values gets lost.

Can someone tell where I am going wrong?

I am stuck here

Sand box: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-elgamal-0zztb

I have added the sandbox link with proper comments. Please have a look. I am a bit new to react.

Help would be really appreciated

### Parent

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "./styles.css";
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import Child from "./Child";
interface IState {
  data: {}[];
  columns: {}[];
  selectedValues: {};
  optionsForColumns: {};
}

interface IProps {}

export default class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

  // Here I have  hardcoded the values, but data and optionsForColumns comes from the backend and it is set inside componentDidMount
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { firstName: "Jack", status: "Submitted", age: "14" },
        { firstName: "Simon", status: "Pending", age: "15" }
      ],
      selectedValues: {},
      columns: [],
      optionsForColumns: {
        firstName: [{ Jack: "4" }, { Simon: "5" }],
        status: [{ Submitted: "5" }, { Pending: "7" }]
      }
    };
  }

  // Get the values for checkboxes that will be sent to child
  getValuesFromKey = (key: any) => {
    let data: any = this.state.optionsForColumns[key];
    let result = data.map((value: any) => {
      let keys = Object.keys(value);
      return {
        field: keys[0],
        checked: false
      };
    });
    return result;
  };

  // Get the consolidated values from child and then pass it for server side filtering
  handleFilter = (fieldName: any, selectedValue: any, modifiedObj: any) => 
  {
    this.setState(
      {
        selectedValues: {
          ...this.state.selectedValues,
          [fieldName]: selectedValue
        }
      },
      () => this.handleColumnFilter(this.state.selectedValues)
    );
  };

  // Function that will make server call based on the checked values from child
  handleColumnFilter = (values: any) => {
    // server side code for filtering
    // After this checkbox content is lost
  };

  // Function where I configure the columns array for the table . (Also data and column fiter values will be set here, in this case I have hardcoded inside constructor)
  componentDidMount() {
    let columns = [
      {
        Header: () => (
          <div>
            <div>
              <Child
                key="firstName"
                name="firstName"
                options={this.getValuesFromKey("firstName")}
                handleFilter={this.handleFilter}
              />
            </div>
            <span>First Name</span>
          </div>
        ),
        accessor: "firstName"
      },
      {
        Header: () => (
          <div>
            <div>
              <Child
                key="status"
                name="status"
                options={this.getValuesFromKey("status")}
                handleFilter={this.handleFilter}
              />
            </div>
            <span>Status</span>
          </div>
        ),
        accessor: "status",
      },
      {
        Header: "Age",
        accessor: "age"
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ columns });
  }

  //Rendering the data table
  render() {
    const { data, columns } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### Child

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button, Checkbox, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
interface IProps {
  options: any;
  name: string;
  handleFilter(val1: any, val2: any, val3: void): void;
}
interface IState {
  showList: boolean;
  selected: [];
  checkboxOptions: any;
}
export default class Child extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: [],
      showList: false,
      checkboxOptions: this.props.options.map((option: any) => option.checked)
    };
  }

  // Checkbox change handler
  handleValueChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, data: any) => {
    const i = this.props.options.findIndex(
      (item: any) => item.field === data.name
    );
    const optionsArr = this.state.checkboxOptions.map(
      (prevState: any, si: any) => (si === i ? !prevState : prevState)
    );
    this.setState({ checkboxOptions: optionsArr });
  };

  //Passing the checked values back to parent
  passSelectionToParent = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const result = this.props.options.map((item: any, i: any) =>
      Object.assign({}, item, {
        checked: this.state.checkboxOptions[i]
      })
    );
    const selected = result
      .filter((res: any) => res.checked)
      .map((ele: any) => ele.field);
    console.log(selected);
    this.props.handleFilter(this.props.name, selected, result);
  };

  //Show/Hide filter
  toggleList = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ showList: !prevState.showList }));
  };

  //Rendering the checkboxes based on the local state, but still it gets lost after filtering happens
  render() {
    let { showList } = this.state;
    let visibleFlag: string;
    if (showList === true) visibleFlag = "visible";
    else visibleFlag = "";
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
          <div
            className={"ui scrolling dropdown column-settings " + visibleFlag}
          >
            <Icon className="filter" onClick={this.toggleList} />
            <div className={"menu transition " + visibleFlag}>
              <div className="menu-item-holder">
                {this.props.options.map((item: any, i: number) => (
                  <div className="menu-item" key={i}>
                    <Checkbox
                      name={item.field}
                      onChange={this.handleValueChange}
                      label={item.field}
                      checked={this.state.checkboxOptions[i]}
                    />
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
              <div className="menu-btn-holder">
                <Button size="small" onClick={this.passSelectionToParent}>
                  Apply
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In the sandbox, the table and nothing is being rendered. Also, can't see the ChildComponent as a dropdown. It seems like arranged in a line. Can you explain the issue here? Is it actually a dropdown? And you are loosing the value on opening the dropdowns again?

Comment: @Abinthaha Will update the sandbox

Comment: @Abinthaha Added the updated sandbox link in the question. Toggling is not working, but that is ok. Now on-click of respective dropdown's 'Apply' there is a backend API that updates the data. And now if I open this dropdown again, checkbox values gets lost! Also I want to preserve the values of all dropdown values so that filter across columns would work correctly

Comment: @Abinthaha Fixed toggling now as well , Can you please find the issue?

Comment: Hi, Am still not able to view the dropdown.

Comment: @Abinthaha Please find the codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-elgamal-0zztb . Click on the filter icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my here below answer was wrong.

In your main component, you set your state.columns just once, when the component did mount. It will never be changed after.

But each time your state.data get changed, your main component get re-rendered and the `ReactTable` component get re-rendered as well with the new data **AND** with your original state.columns which get no info about the selected options.

I think you should reconstruct your column object after each update, passing in your Child components a prop like `selectedOption`.

Your child props depend on your state.selectedValues and state.data.
You can reconstruct your column object in your render(). I'm using a method buildColumns to get the details out of render.

You don't need the `columns`property in your state.

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { firstName: "Jack", status: "Submitted", age: "14" },
        { firstName: "Simon", status: "Pending", age: "15" },
        { firstName: "Pete", status: "Approved", age: "16" },
        { firstName: "Lucas", status: "Rejected", age: "19" }
      ],
      selectedValues: {},
    };
  }
...
buildColumns = ({ data, selectedValues = {} }) => {
    const { firstName, status } = selectedValues
    return [
      {
        Header: () => (
          <div>
            <div style={{ position: "absolute", marginLeft: "10px" }}>
              <Child
                key="firstName"
                name="firstName"
                options={this.getValuesFromKey(data, "firstName")}
                selectedOption={firstName}
                handleFilter={this.handleFilter}
              />
            </div>
            <span>First Name</span>
          </div>
        ),
        accessor: "firstName",
        sortable: false,
        show: true,
        displayValue: " First Name"
      },
      {
        Header: () => (
          <div>
            <div style={{ position: "absolute", marginLeft: "10px" }}>
              <Child
                key="status"
                name="status"
                options={this.getValuesFromKey(data, "status")}
                selectedOption={status}
                handleFilter={this.handleFilter}
              />
            </div>
            <span>Status</span>
          </div>
        ),
        accessor: "status",
        sortable: false
      },
      {
        Header: "Age",
        accessor: "age"
      }
    ];
  }

  render() {
    const { data, selectedValues } = this.state;
    const columns = this.buildColumns({ data, selectedValues })
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

You still have to use the `selectedOption` props inside your Child component to precheck your checkbox.

---

old (and wrong) answer:

When you get filtered data and set your state with it, now that your state.data has changed, it will re-render the Child component which get props derived from it.

This will reinitialize the state of your Child component to its `{selected: []}`value.

To prevent that, you should make your Child component a 'controlled component' by keeping your state only in your Main component, and passing the info of the selected option by props: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Is it possible for you edit the snippet please? I am bit new to react

Comment: Thanks again! What do you mean reconstructing? If you meant reconstructing the entire column object, It would again add lot of complexity. Could you show me a code snippet or edit the existing sandbox? I am not getting your point, Would definitely mark it as correct answer if it satisfies

Comment: I edited my answer again, I hope it will be clearer like so.

Comment: But still unsuccessful

Comment: I don't see anything in this link related to what I suggested. You still build your `columns` object in `ComponentDidMount`, so it's done only once and it doesn't get updated.
Did you try what I suggested to you?

Comment: Yes . The logic was getting complex and complex . And also                 selectedOption={firstName} would not solve as each column has a set of options to be selected from. Here it would not map properly